# Force Windows 10 to install automatic WSUS update

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file, windows-10-upgrade, wsus

A Windows 10 PC is connected to a WSUS intranet server, like a lot of other PCs here which are functioning fine, but others do not receive WSUS updates.
I've written .bat file to force remote pc to download and install the update, and .. restart but doesn't work fine !! 
can people with good health help me..

```
CODE 
@Echo off
 cd\
 Echo Procedura di reset aggiornamenti WSUS
 REM ****************************
 REM * Variabili di procedura *
 REM ****************************

 set varcomputer= ////
 set timerestart=360
 goto force_up
REM :NOMEMACCHINA

 Exit

 REM ****************************
 REM * PROCEDURE*
 REM ****************************

 :force_up
echo WSUS Force Update %varcomputer%
   wuauclt /resetauthorization /detectnow /force \\%varcomputer%
   wuauclt  /updatenow /force \\%varcomputer%
echo Shutting down %varcomputer%.
  shutdown -r -m  \\%varcomputer% -t %timerestart% -c "Il PC si riavvierà automaticamente per effettuare degli aggiornamenti di sicurezza entro %timerestart% secondi. Si prega di salvare e chiudere i documenti aperti."
 goto %varcomputer

echo ****** Procedura inviata *****
:FINE
pause
pause
pause
echo ****** Procedura inviata *****
pause
pause
```

Comment: "do not receive" means the search takes forever? Can you please add a screenshot of the Windows Update status in control panel? Do the Windows event logs of those machines show any error?

Comment: Use this powershell command to generate `WindowsUpdate.log`, then, check the errors in it: `Get-WindowsUpdateLog`

Comment: HOW TO USE IN REMOTE CMD ?

Comment: Just use remote desktop to connect and create the control panel screenshot (and check logs). Then add the screenshot to your question.

Comment: We cannot use remote desktop or security issue to connect to other PC, but we can use software vnc, and domain policy distribuite update with Wsus. How i can Force with. Bat script file?

Comment: It does not matter if you collect the logs and screenshots by remote desktop, VNC or by walking to the machine. No one can give you a magic script without analyzing the root cause.

Comment: If you're on a network with WSUS your question is about business IT and needs to be addressed to the business IT staff, not us.